# Select records based on a non unique column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My table looks like the following:

[image: The "smp_audit_detail" table.]

I want to be able to select a number of records based on the `auditidentity` column.

I tried using `LIMIT` but this only limits the number of rows returned but each audit can have an undetermined number of rows.

I tried using `DESTINCT` but this returned only one row from each record.

In short,

> Number of rows != number of audits

How do I select a number of them?

Edit: For clarity, each coloured outline is regarded as an "Audit".

[image: Audits outlined]

Comment: And what should be your output?

Comment: show your sample output

Comment: There are around 70,000 rows but only 1335 unique "auditidentity" rows. I want to limit my output to be say.. 100 of those.

Comment: @Geditdk how about `limit 100` ??

Comment: so you don't want to repeat row with same `auditidentity` ?? or what ??

Comment: There are multiple rows per record, using `LIMIT` wouldn't return 100 audits. If I only return 100 rows that could be only say... 10 audits if each audit has 10 rows.

Comment: i really dont understand whats your actual problem, if possible do an edit on your question and include input and output so that it can be easily understand

Comment: I've added another image showing what an "Audit" is. It's these that I need to `LIMIT`.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? It's not clear from the question.

Comment: Each of those box's is an audit, I want 100 of those returned regardless of how many rows they have. The `auditidentity` is unique to the record as a whole, not the row itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyones help, a colleague of mine found the answer:

```
SELECT * FROM smp_audit_detail WHERE auditidentity IN   
(SELECT DISTINCT auditidentity  FROM smp_audit_detail LIMIT 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY auditidentity ORDER BY auditidentity) AS itemNumber,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY auditidentity) AS auditNbr,
            tbl.*
        FROM @tbl AS tbl
    ) AS tbl2
WHERE 
    tbl2.itemNumber<=100
    AND tbl2.auditNbr<=2
```

Comment: @dude : I am not super acquainted in PostgreSQL. But it should work. Tested with a `TOP` in mssql

Comment: @Arion Thanks for the response, unfortunately this returns only the first row of each audit. The number of audits returned is correct, but I need the additional rows also.

Comment: Change  `tbl.rowNbr=1` to `tbl.rowNbr<=100` and get rid of limit.

Comment: Clever stuff, I see what this is doing but it returns over 7000 rows. The `tbl.rowNbr<=100` dictates how many rows from each audit can be returned but I can't limit the total number of audits.

Comment: @Geditdk : I updated the answer. With that query you can control how many items you get and how maybe audits you get